# Send slider values over MQTT

Tags: javascript, react-native, mqtt

I am new at React Native and I would like to use mqtt in an app. I am trying to send slider values over mqtt. I installed mqtt library following [this repository](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js). The mqtt part of the code on its own works and the sliders part on its own works, but when I put both codes together I can't collect slider values to send over mqtt.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Slider, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import  { connect } from 'mqtt';

var client  = connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sliderValue: '0',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Text style = {{ color: 'black' }}>
          Value of this slider is : {this.state.sliderValue_1}
        </Text>

        <Slider
          maximumValue = "2"
          minimumValue = "0"
          step = "1"
          value_1 = {this.state.sliderValue}
          onValueChange = {sliderValue_1 => this.setState({ sliderValue_1 })}
        />

        <Text style = {{ color: 'black' }}>
          Value of this slider is : {this.state.sliderValue_2}
        </Text>

        <Slider
          maximumValue = "2"
          minimumValue = "0"
          step = "1"
          value_2 = {this.state.sliderValue_2}
          onValueChange = {sliderValue_2 => this.setState({ sliderValue_2 })}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('topic_1');
  client.subscribe('topic_2');
  client.publish('topic_1', (value_1));
  client.publish('topic_2', (value_2));
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(message.toString())
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

Comment: "I can't collect slider values" ... what does that mean?  You are sending out MQTT packets with blank payloads?  Error messages?  From your code, it looks like the MQTT payloads will be blank since your .on('connect' will most likely fire before there are any values added to value_1 & value_2.  Put those client.publish() commands where you are setting your value_x vars and see if that works.